# Backup plan for MySQL NDB cluster databse not innoDB

Tags: mysql, backup, ndbcluster

I have a Database which will grow more than 250GB all data is in NDB engine(2 datanodes) and no other mysql engine used for data store.

- What are the best approaches or plans for MySQL Cluster NDB database backup.
- Is MySQL Enterprise Backup( part of MySQL Cluster CGE) or any other tool does backup for NDB?
- Can a beginner like me do these backup of NDB easily or needs specialised skills?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go through some more articles regarding cluster to make better understanding.
I have put here the steps of taking cluster backup and restore with 4 data node scenario.

**1.MySQL Cluster Native Backup Tool (ONLINE Backup) and Restore**

1.1

```
ndb_mgm> START BACKUP <Option>

<Option>:NOWAIT, WAIT STARTED, WAIT COMPLETED
```

**NOWAIT** - This returns a response to the display immediately and             begins the backup without waiting for responses from the data nodes.

**WAIT STARTED** - This returns a response to the display only when a response is returned from all the data nodes saying the backup has begun.

**WAIT COMPLETED** - This returns a response to the display only when a response is returned from all the data nodes saying that the backups have been completed successfully.
In most cases, using the START BACKUP WAIT COMPLETED is the best option:

```
 ndb_mgm> START BACKUP WAIT COMPLETED
```

Files that are created on Disk

1.1.1   **.ctl** - This group of files (labeled backup-..ctl) is          the metadata from the cluster for each data node.

1.1.2   **.log** - This group of files (labeled backup-..log)             contain the UNDO log files to keep the backup consistent and to ensure that no locks are needed during the backup process.

1.1.3   **.Data** - This group of files (labeled backup--                    ..Data) contains the data for the entire system.

1.2 To interrupt the backup in progress.

If the abort was successful, a message will be displayed stating this and issuing an error (which is to be expected).If a backup id is entered, but there is no backup occurring that is associated with that id, there is a response but without an error being issued:

```
ndb_mgm> ABORT BACKUP <backup id> 
ndb_mgm> ABORT BACKUP 6
```

1.3  `ndb_mgm> <node_id> REPORT BackupStatus`

This command provides a status report on a cluster backup at anytime during the backup for node_id, or for all data nodes using ALL.

1.4  **Restoring cluster Backup**

1.4.1 Shutdown the cluster and then Restart Management Node

1.4.1.1

```
 ndb_mgm>SHUTDOWN
```

1.4.1.2

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/ndb_mgmd
```

1.4.2   Start and empty the data nodes:-

Prior to restoring a backup, it is important to start and empty the data nodes.This is accomplished by starting each data node with the --initial option.

```
./ndbd  --initial
```

1.4.3   Restore the Cluster Backup

1.4.3.1 `ndb_mgm> ENTER SINGLE USER MODE [Node-Id of First Free Slot]`

1.4.3.2 In an operating system console, enter the following                     command from the /var/lib/mysqlcluster/BACKUP/BACKUP-1/ directory:

```
ndb_restore -m -r -b 1 -n 2   /* -- For First DataNode*/
ndb_restore -r -b 1 -n 3      /*-- For Second DataNode */
```

1.4.3.3

```
ndb_mgm> EXIT SINGLE USER MODE
```

**2. MySQL Cluster Backup through MySQLDump Utility**

2.1

```
shell> mysqldump -u root -p --lock-tables Dd_Name > Db_Name-backup.sql
```

2.2 Restoring mysqldump Files

```
shell> mysql -u root -p < Db_Name-backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Cluster includes its own on-line (hot) backup tools:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-backup.html

To further simplify administration, MySQL Cluster Manager 1.2, part of the commercial MySQL Cluster CGE automates the integrated on-line back-up and restore functionality of MySQL Cluster, so you no longer need to log-in to each individual data node to view and / or restore a backup. Using MySQL Cluster Manager 1.2, restore operations are reduced to a single, simple command.